# Removing figures from end of the pdf file

Tags: table-of-contents, floats

I am going to submit a paper on arxiv, but I have a problem in the pdf generated by arxiv. It copies all my figures at the end of the paper. I want to remove those figures and just have them at their proper place.

Comment: Not sure, but if they ask it like this, they probably have their reasons and they don't want you to change this behavior. Just add "[Figure 4 about here]" texts and you are ok. They will use some method to scale and place the figures that (this method) is supposed to be their problem...

Comment: Remove the figure environment and apply the `caption` package, replace `\caption{foo}` by `\captionof{figure}{foo}` -- the figures appear at the position you stated them.

Answer (score 1):

Does Arxiv restrict the use of the `float` package? You can typically force figure placement with

```
\usepackage{float}
```

in your preamble and use the `H` specifier

```
\begin{figure}[H]

\end{figure}
```

around your figure.

Comment: The instructions [at Arxiv](https://arxiv.org/help/submit_tex) do not state what package is used. The instructions recommend that figures be included in-line simply using `\includegraphics`. This may mean, the use of the `figure` environment and floats is to be avoided. I've upvoted the answer from @ChristianHupfer accordingly.